# Selecting correct radio button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 4 radio buttons and a data table that has a row that matches each radio button value. When I select a data table row the corresponding radio button is selected. I can cycle through all data table rows and watch each corresponding radio button get selected. If I select a data table row that has the same radio button value of a previously selected row or go back and re-select a row, the radio buttons stop being selected. Can someone tell/show me why my radio buttons are not being selected the 2nd time through?

```
<-- data table populated with 5 rows of data. Two rows have 3 for the radio button value -->
<table id="reviewerDatatable" class="display compact">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Review Date</th>
            <th>Reminder Sent</th>
            <th>Review Interval</th> <-- column with radio button values (3,6,12,24) -->
            <th>Is Active</th>
            <th>Actionee</th>
            <th>Artifact</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<-- Section of form with radio buttons -->
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-3">Reminder Intervals</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reminderInterval" value="3">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="reminderInterval1">
                3 Months
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reminderInterval" value="6">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="reminderInterval2">
                6 Months
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reminderInterval" value="12">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="reminderInterval3">
                12 Months
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reminderInterval" value="24">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="reminderInterval4">
                24 Months
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<-- Click event for data table -->
$('#reviewerDatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var rowData = table.row(this).data();

    $.each(rowData, function (name, val) {
        var $el = $('[name="' + name + '"]'),
            type = $el.attr('type');

        switch (type) {
            case 'checkbox':
                $el.prop('checked', val);
                break;
    
    <-- This works and selects the corresponding radio button on the 1st time through -->
            case 'radio':
                $el.filter('[value=' + val + ']').attr('checked', true);
                break;

            case 'date':
                var now = new Date(val);
                var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var formattedDate = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
                $el.val(formattedDate);
                break;

            default:
                $el.val(val);
        }
    });
});

<!-- Data used to generate the rows -->
<!--https://datatables.net/examples/styling/compact.html-->
<script src="../../lib/plugins/jquery.datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

{
    "ArtifactData": [
        {
            "reviewerArtifactId": 1,
            "lastReviewDate": "06/01/2019",
            "dateReminderSent": "06/01/2020",
            "reminderInterval": "6",
            "artifactIsActive": true,
            "actionee": "Superman",
            "artifact": "Lois' Diary"
        },
        {
            "reviewerArtifactId": 2,
            "lastReviewDate": "07/01/2019",
            "dateReminderSent": "07/01/2020",
            "reminderInterval": "3",
            "artifactIsActive": true,
            "actionee": "Batman",
            "artifact": "Joker's Criminal Plans"
        },
        {
            "reviewerArtifactId": 3,
            "lastReviewDate": "08/01/2019",
            "dateReminderSent": "08/01/2020",
            "reminderInterval": "24",
            "artifactIsActive": false,
            "actionee": "Spiderman",
            "artifact": "Class Schedule"
        },
        {
            "reviewerArtifactId": 4,
            "lastReviewDate": "09/01/2019",
            "dateReminderSent": "09/01/2020",
            "reminderInterval": "3",
            "artifactIsActive": true,
            "actionee": "Hulk",
            "artifact": "Any artifact he wants"
        },
        {
            "reviewerArtifactId": 5,
            "lastReviewDate": "10/01/2019",
            "dateReminderSent": "10/01/2020",
            "reminderInterval": "12",
            "artifactIsActive": true,
            "actionee": "Thor",
            "artifact": "Mjolnir Specs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does anything show in your console? Try putting a console.log inside of the radio case statement to make sure it has the correct values

Comment: The correct value shows up each time in my console, no matter how many times I select the row.

Comment: @Wannabe Can you add `tr` data as well where you click at ?

Comment: The rows are generated using JSON data. I've added it and a link to the jquery plugin that populates the table.